# Extra row after border

Tags: html, css

If i use this code, unfortunatelly i get extra "row" after the dotted border. Could you help me, how can i set the "space" to 0, after the border?

```
<td style="height:50px; line-height:10px; margin-top:10px;" >
   <div class="test"><p>test line 1</p></div>
   <div class="test"><p>test line 1</p></div>
   <div class="test"><p>test line 1</p></div>
   <div class="test"><p>test line 1</p></div>

</td>




.test {
    border-top-style:dotted; 
    border-top-width:1px; 
    border-top-color:#999;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-bottom:-10px;

 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: A screenshot or link to the site would be helpful ;)

Comment: http://www.kepfeltoltes.hu/view/100106/dot_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not write on this way?

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  .test {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .test li{
    border-top: 1px #999 dotted;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  }
</style>

<ul class="test">
  <li>test line 1</li>
  <li>test line 2</li>
  <li>test line 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS class test is not being used in your example above. Maybe you forgot to paste some of the relevant parts. And have you set

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

In the CSS for your table?

Comment: sorry..old code. i edited it. This border-collapse not work. After the border i no need space...

Answer (score 0):

A margin has no meaning on a table cell. Do you want to set the padding?

The HTML seems strange. You have a single table cell with a margin with four divs inside. Could you post the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

Tried setting `.test p { margin: 0; }`?

Comment: its not work. If i not use border, then no space between the lines, so something with the border.